# Is there a vector data in MariaDB or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is there a vector data type in MySQL or MariaDB? I want to fetch rows within a certain euclidean distance from a 144 dimensional vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no vector data type in MySQL. Neither is there an array datatype as of 5.x series. 
ANSI/ISO standards define an *array* datatype, so MySQL will eventually implement an array datatype. There is an [open item](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2081) for implementing array data type which is currently not active.

While arrays are not exactly vectors, if arrays are not yet immediately planned to be implemented, then no support for vector datatypes can be expected in the near future.

Comment: Clear and to the point. That's the kind of answer I like. Thank you!

Comment: I find it interesting that they plan vector support for AI stuff before implementing basic array support.